# Netstat -i redirection problem

Tags: script, netstat

When I run this command `netstat -t 1 -i 2>&1 > $NETStat_OUT_FILE &` inside a script , the output of netstat does not get redirected to the file.. Could any one find a solution for this ?

Comment: As response to your comments, try opening output with tail -f output.file , that way you will see it as soon as it's written.

Answer (score 0):

What's the whole line? Chances are the problem is in the declaration of the $NETStat_OUT_FILE variable, because the rest seems to work normally.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the declaration.. The problem is arising for me only if i specify the "-i" flag ..

Comment: What's the whole script or at least the part that sets $NETStat_OUT_FILE?

Comment: sorry.. there is no problem as such..but when i try to read the output file immediately after execution it puts out a blank file.. the redirection program takes time to write the output onto the output file..i'm able to view the output if i open it after sometime

Answer (score 0):

Does the file get created at all?  Try changing "$NETStat_OUT_FILE" to "${NETStat_OUT_FILE:?}" to catch the possibility of a typo.  It's possible that the output is being buffered, so that you won't see anything in the file until after some block of text (probably 512 bytes) has been buffered and flushed.

Comment: `PROJ_DIR="/cac/u01/sharatds/ScriptsNETStat_OUT_FILE="$PROJ_DATA_DIR
PROJ_DATA_DIR="$PROJ_DIR/data"
NETStat_OUT_FILE="$PROJ_DATA_DIR/NETstat.outputfile.lap01.$1.txt";
 netstat -t 1 2>&1 > $NETStat_OUT_FILE &

Comment: sorry.. there is no problem as such..but when i try to read the output file immediately after execution it puts out a blank file.. the redirection program takes time to write the output onto the output file..i'm able to view the output if i open it after sometime